# WSL process causing DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using Bash on Ubuntu for Windows on Windows 10.

Disclaimer: I'm relatively new to Windows. Have almost exclusively used unix systems

I'm downloading ~1 mil images, in groups of up to 100k, by executing the following script in WSL, ($1 is the target folder where the images are downloaded):

```
#!/bin/bash
SECONDS=0
cat "$1/pics.csv" | xargs -n 1 -P 10 wget -q -P "$1/"
echo "Elapsed $SECONDS seconds"
echo "Adding .jpg extentions"
mmv "$1/*_small" "$1/#1.jpg"
find "$1" -name pics.csv -type f -delete
```

The process spawns up to 8 threads to download images, renames them and then deletes the csv the urls were read from. The first couple of times the script is started it completes but then it suddenly stops and results in a BSOD.

I've run it multiple times on my Mac without failure. I had to port my project to Windows 10 and want to use WSL as it should be able to run the bash scripts.

I've checked the Event Viewer for error logs - the source seems to be DistributedCOM with the error but I cannot see how that could be the case as it runs fine the first few times.

> The application-specific permission settings do not grant Local Activation permission for the COM Server application with CLSID 
>   {D63B10C5-BB46-4990-A94F-E40B9D520160}
>    and APPID 
>   {9CA88EE3-ACB7-47C8-AFC4-AB702511C276}
>    to the user DESKTOP-E01P1DA[Username] SID (S-1-5-21-2149831090-3283936149-3974900866-1001) from address LocalHost (Using LRPC) running in the application container Unavailable SID (Unavailable). This security permission can be modified using the Component Services administrative tool.

Does anyone have an idea what could be the cause and solution for this?

Comment: See if [this article](https://shauncassells.wordpress.com/2015/09/28/windows-10-event-10016-fix-the-application-specific-permission-settings-do-not-grant-local-activation-permission-for-the-com-server-application-with-clsid-d63b10c5-bb46-4990-a94f-e40b9d520160-and-a/) solves your problem.

Comment: Try to add some seconds in between the commands, for example use `sleep 5`.